# Some images won't show when moved Wordpress site to another domain on same server

Tags: mysql, html, wordpress

I've developed a new wordpress website on a testing domain name on our server.
I had set the site up ready to go live... but I had to move the wordpress website onto another domain name that we are also hosting on our server.

So what I did was copy all root folder content from the testing domain name and pasted the content into the new domain name's root folder.

I then logged into wordpress, changed all the necessary settings like WORDPRESS URL and SITE ADDRESS URL as well as image absolute urls in each and every individual pages to make sure that I've got the right URL for everything.

When I click on MEDIA, I can see all the images like normal.

Great ... then I go and check the website live and I see that there are a lot of images that are missing! They are all in the MEDIA panel - but do not show up on the website!

I then double check that all images are pathed correctly ... and they all are.

Now why do SOME images show up and others don't?
I've even tried to add a new photo and use that photo in place of another photo that isn't showing up and that new photo doesn't even show up.

Where does my problem lie?

For example, 1 slideshow on my website which isn't showing images, give me an "image not found" error for a image:

```
Image not found: http://www.domain.com/wp-content/themes/natural
/lib/timthumb.php?src=http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/breakfast-gallery-011.jpg&w=610&h=0&zc=1
```

Comment: What happens when you put the full path to one of the broken image files directly in the address bar? Do the images that show up and those that don't have a different format? Check the file extensions.

Comment: I've found with my own blog that Wordpress actually hard codes in a direct full-length url to some elements. What it came down to for me was Wordpress pulling from an SQL database which had the links "hard coded" in.

Comment: Good tip, I should have thought about that. I just checked now, put the full URL in the address bar of the image(s) that don't show up, and they DO load up. Every pic is a jpg and I've checked to see all extensions and they are correct :(

Comment: @DevinHurd - Hmmm this is what I was thinking that could be my problem but am hoping there is an easier solution because I am no sql expert. I even downloaded a SEARCH AND REPLACE plugin to replace the old domain name with new domain name in the database. Did that and it didn't work.

Comment: NOTE: Before I did the "migration" - I did export the website in xml. I'm not sure if that will be in any use?

Comment: What's strange is that the photos in the gallery [gallery] < shortcode - shows the all the images!

Comment: Please see my updated post above (see code I've inserted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I am going to answer my question with some advice.
It's clear that some of my images were 'hard coded' as devin mentioned as I could not find a logical reason for some not showing (even when I looked at the tabular data in MySQL) and because I'm not a database engineer / developer - I wasn't prepared to dive too deep into that with the possibility of causing further issues... so I decided to take down the entire wordpress site, create a new database, re-install wordpress and I imported an exported xml file that I created and saved (luckily) before 'migrating sites'.

**Advice:**

**1)** Whether you migrate a wordpress site or not, always backup your website regularly by creating an export of your wordpress structure. It may save you a lot of work in future.

**2)** If you're an amateur or beginner at development and MYSQL like myself, I'd suggest you create your wordpress site on the actual domain name you want it on. This will save you from 'migration' headaches as I've just experienced ... and a lot of time. Learn from my mistakes. Although there is probably a solution to my question above, it's out of my expertise / knowledge and could be out of yours too... so make it easy for yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not that the image URls are hardcoded only. The last portion of the URL is harcoded, but you will most likely have "/wp-content/" embedded in the URL which indicates that the image's URL string is dynamically created. I looked in my wp_postmeta table and there were all of the partial image URls ( like this - 2013/03/expanse2.jpg ). Now where is the beginning part of this URL and the domain name? The domain name is the part that is actually missing from the all of the image urls in my case. I dug into the database a little deeper using phpmyadmin ( but i recommend Webmin if you can get it up and running ). I ran into the "home" field in the "wp_options" table. Asked Google what a proper "home url" would be for wordpress, which brought me to this page ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url ) , and this line was in there ( home_url() is located in wp-includes/link-template.php. ). Went to that file and found that it controls how URLs are built, but not uploaded image urls specifically. In the end i went into a page that had an image, looked at the advanced settings and found the image URL was just missing the domain. I used the wonderful search and replace script to repair it. Done